# selecting male and female seats based on age

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a passenger_information table where the columns are like `booking_id, gender_id, passenger_name and passenger_age`. I need to select the number of adults seats both male and female booked and also the child seats both male and female.

The `gender_id` table defines 24 as male and 25 as female. To differentiate between child and adults seats we use `passenger_age` where the age for the child should not exceed 11 years.

I am trying to write a query to get the details based on `booking_id` but failing miserably.

Can some one help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somnething like this:

```
select 
      booking_id
      , sum(case when gender_id = 24 and passenger_age > 11 then 1 else 0 end) adult_male
      , sum(case when gender_id = 25 and passenger_age > 11 then 1 else 0 end) adult_female
      , sum(case when gender_id = 24 and passenger_age <= 11 then 1 else 0 end) child_male
      , sum(case when gender_id = 24 and passenger_age <= 11 then 1 else 0 end) child_female
from passenger_information
group by booking_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. That's what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Group by AND UNION.

```
    Select
    booking_id, 
    CASE gender_id WHEN 24 then 'Adult - Male'
    ELSE 'Adult - Female' END as 'Gender',
    count(booking_id)
FROM passenger_information
    WHERE passenger_age>11
    Group by booking_id,gender_id
UNION 
Select
    booking_id,  
    CASE gender_id WHEN 24 then 'Child - Male'
    ELSE 'Child - Female' END as 'Gender',
    count(booking_id)
FROM passenger_information
    WHERE passenger_age<=11
    Group by booking_id,gender_id
```