# Oracle - counting the result of a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, count, case

### The Goal / Background

- I am combing through a workorder system to see if workorders meet certain criteria

  - (e.g. if they're not stage 3, stage 2, or even stage 1).
- These "stages" have been defined by management.
- I would like to group by the year reported, then the craft, and then see how many work orders for that grouping are in each of those 3 "not stages".

### The Query

```
select yearreported
, theleadcraft
, count(NotStage3)
, count(NotStage2)
, count(NotStage1)

from
(
    select extract(year from reportdate) as YearReported
    , Nvl(leadcraft, 'NONE') as TheLeadCraft
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE') then 1 else 0 END as NotStage3
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP') then 1 else 0 END as NotStage2
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP', 'WORKDONE') then 1 else 0  END as NotStage1
    from workorder
) query 

group by yearreported, theleadcraft;
;
```

### The Problem / Question

- This appears to work, but all counts for notstage1, notstage2, and notstage1 come out the same, despite querying for some situations and finding some that I know to be different.
- Is this the correct way to implement a case statement that I want to count?
- Should I be using DECODE() instead?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [selecting male and female seats based on age](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720774/selecting-male-and-female-seats-based-on-age)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1's and 0's both COUNT() the same -- possibly you want to SUM(), or to COUNT() either 1 or null.

Comment: Thank you! It was indeed a brain fart -- I had been using count earlier when looking at the problem in a different way and didn't adjust my aggregate function. :) Thank you!

Comment: Zero counts as 1. How confusing :) Null was the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Count is not counting NULL -s. Try this:

```
, CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE') then 1 END as NotStage3
, CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP') then 1 END as NotStage2
, CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP', 'WORKDONE') then 1 END as NotStage1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `decode`.

The way you have your query written, you really want `sum()`, not `count()`:

```
select yearreported, theleadcraft, sum(NotStage3), sum(NotStage2), sum(NotStage1)
```

The function `count()` has a misleading name when applied to a column (in my opinion).  It is counting the number of non-NULL values.  Since "1" and "0" are both non-NULL, they get counted.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it by simple modification on your statement above

try this :

```
select yearreported
, theleadcraft
, count(decode (NotStage3, 1,1) )
, count(decode (NotStage2, 1,1) )
, count(decode (NotStage1, 1,1) )

from
(
    select extract(year from reportdate) as YearReported
    , Nvl(leadcraft, 'NONE') as TheLeadCraft
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE') then 1 else 0 END as NotStage3
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP') then 1 else 0 END as NotStage2
    , CASE when status not in ('CAN', 'CLOSE', 'COMP', 'WORKDONE') then 1 else 0  END as NotStage1
    from workorder
) query 

group by yearreported, theleadcraft;
```

regards,

Comment: this trick by using decode function which will return 1 for 1s values, all other values will not decoded then the decode function will return null so it will not counted.